# Resource specification not allowed here for source level below 1.7

Tags: java, compiler-errors, try-with-resources

I am trying to open an `OutputStream` resource in a try with resources block:

```
try (OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()) {
    output.write(query.getBytes(charset));
}
```

However, I got a compilation error:

> Resource specification not allowed here for source level below 1.7

Is there an equivalent for 1.6 or do I have to convert my project to 1.7?

Comment: Why is the question related to gwt?

Comment: In which line you get These message?

Comment: It is better to use java7 because java6 is outdated

Comment: java7 is also outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
try {
    OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
    output.write(query.getBytes(charset));
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You'd need/want to close the stream in a finally block, and make sure you don't shadow any previous exception. The equivalent Java 6 code is given in the JLS IIRC.